# When does creating a .sql backup with mysqldump become too large?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Is there a limit to how large a database can be when executing a .sql backup using mysqldump, or will you run into server problems before that - will the server not be able to take such a large backup file?

I'm thinking in the levels of:

- 1 - 10GB
- 10 - 100GB
- 100 - 500GB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only think of three(3) things that can cause a mysqldump to be too large

## PROBLEM #1 : Disabling Extended Inserts

Extended Inserts ([**--extended-insert**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert)) is on by default via the [--opt option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt). If you issue `--skip-opt` or `--skip-extended-insert`, every INSERT command will quickly become hundreds or every thousands. Such a mysqldump can still be loaded but takes longer because of the absence of batch inserts.

## PROBLEM #2 : BLOB Data

When dumping a table with BLOB data, there is a small possibility that the dump may not be portable. To make such data portable, some resort to the [--hex-blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) option. This write the BLOB as text-represented hexadecimal. When using this, you should expect a more bloated mysqldump.

#### CAVEAT : Don't use --hex-blob and --skip-extended-insert together

## PROBLEM #3 : [**MySQL Packet**](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833)

Most people take the [MySQL Packet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets/19139#19139) for granted. [Some mysqldump could time out if you not paying attention](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323). [mysqldump's default for `max-allowed-packet` in 24M](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet). Extended inserts can benefit from a larger packet. It could possibly increase the number of rows per extended INSERT command. The savings in size might be nominal at best. Notwithstanding, the larger the dump, the slightly better the reduction of size might be.

## UPDATE 2015-02-13 12:37 EST

If your main concern is just sheer size vs. hardware constraints, you dump like this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppasswword ... | gzip > mybackup.sql.gz
```

and restore like this

```
gzip -d < mybackup.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -ppasswword
```

You could use [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) instead of gzip ([Pros and cons of bzip vs gzip?](https://superuser.com/questions/205223/pros-and-cons-of-bzip-vs-gzip))

Comment: Great. Then I shouldn't worry about our database and growing out of mysqldump as the basic export option yet.

Comment: +1 for compression. You could also take a look at a parallel implementation of your favorite compression utility, for example: pigz.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors that could come into play. Size of RAM, whether your software is using any timeouts (e.g.: phpMyAdmin), your own patience.

In general, though, I would expect a server that can generate a backup should be able to restore it.

Comment: So mysqldump can generate a dump file for a 500gb database as long as the hardware is enough?