# Windows crashes on doing sql dump

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, windows, mysql-5.1

Windows simply crashes and opens the blue screen for dumping physical memory on trying to import sql dump.
Blue screen error: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
So far I have tried 4 methods:

1. Through workbench

   Through command prompt using mysql command

   Through command prompt using mysql -h command

   Through ant: ant import-database after creating data-sync folder

Windows crashes in all the 3 cases

Before each new trial I un-install mysql and delete the MySQL folder from Program Files and MySQL data from Program Data. Size of dump files is 2.75 GB.

**MySQL versions I have tried with:**

1. mysql-5.5.44

   mysql-5.5.33.2

   mysql-5.5.44.0

**System configurations:**

- Workbench: 6.3.30
- My system has 12 GB RAM
- Windows 7 Service Pack 1
- AMD A6-5400B APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.60GHz

Comment: Does the import succeed on a different computer?

Comment: Please provide your dump to the developers via http://bugs.mysql.com .

Comment: @MichaelGreen: Yes the import works perfectly fine on a different computer.

Comment: Actually the import does not succeed entirely. It crashes a few times but then it imports anyway.

Comment: Tell us the exact mysqldump command you tried. Tell us which version of MYSQL and from which OS (is it from Windows or Linux?), you have taken the dump. Also tell us what exact command you used to take the dump and how big it is.

Answer (score 1):

That error is [nonsequiter](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur) with regards to MySQL. This would especially be true if your Windows server crashed for reasons other than MySQL. There are [ways to fix IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL](http://www.deskdecode.com/how-to-fix-stop-0x0000000a-irql_-not_-less_-than_-equal/).

However, if you are reloading a mysqldump and it is the only reason Windows crashes, you may have to accommodate Windows until you fix the `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` error by applying one of the following suggestions (but not both):

## SUGGESTION #1 : Change the mysqldump layout

You may have to create another mysqldump using [--hex-blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob) or [--skip-extended-insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert) but not both. That way, MySQL will ingest data in bite-sized chunks instead of woofing down thousands of rows of data. See my answer to the post [When does creating a .sql backup with mysqldump become too large?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91903/when-does-creating-a-sql-backup-with-mysqldump-become-too-large/91911#91911) for clarification.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Change the [MySQL Packet](https://superuser.com/questions/273730/what-does-the-mysql-max-allowed-packet-setting-actually-control/273833#273833) size

Most people take the [MySQL Packet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets/19139#19139) for granted. [Some mysqldump could time out if you not paying attention](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps/5323#5323). [mysqldump's default for `max-allowed-packet` in 24M](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet). Extended inserts can benefit from a larger packet upon reload. It could possibly increase the number of rows per extended INSERT command. Since a mysqldump can trigger a crash, you could experiment with  slightly larger values (the max size is `1G`). The MySQL Packet never starts out at [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet). The size starts out at [net_buffer_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length) and expands to [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_max_allowed_packet) on demand.

## EPILOGUE

These two suggestions is really no more than a BandAid for your scenario. You need to do your homework and fix the `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` first before resorting to workarounds.

Comment: SUGGESTION #2 failed completely. I tried with packets of size 33554432 and 900554432. In both the cases windows crashed.