# Copying MySQL schema, some tables not getting recognized!

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, schema, mysqldump

From the 'data' folder of my colleague I copied the entire 'MyDatabase' folder and pasted that in my own 'data' folder.
Now, some tables are getting recognized while others are not.
**All the tables are in .frm format.

Some random tables are not getting imported. All the tables that I have are InnoDB with only two MyISAM tables. Many InnoDB tables and both the MyISAM tables are working fine. It's just that some random tables are not working.

Comment: Just don't do that. Don't copy and move data directories. Use mysqldump.

Comment: @ypercube: Thats what I have been trying for weeks. Checkout this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310239/windows-crashes-on-doing-sql-dump

Comment: I can vote to bring that question in this site but please do edit it and add details of what exact command you run, how big the dump was,  what version of MySQL you have on Windows, how the dump was taken, in what OS and mysql version the dump was taken, etc.

Comment: @ypercube: My bad. I have updated all the details here...
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/windows-crashes-on-doing-sql-dump

Answer (score 1):

The ".frm" file holds table definition. You might want to check [mysql file-types](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-related-file-types-and-basic-information) info.

Usually when you move data-base physically do following:

- Shutdown mysql
- Copy datafiles to datadir
- make sure mysql has full permissions on it:
  `chown mysql:mysql datadir/ -R`
- start mysql

So, make sure that the tables which are not "visible" have proper permissions for mysql to access it.

Also, when you say you moved "database" do you mean all-databases-on-server or single-database?
If your database have innodb tables you **cannot** move them like this!

Comment: I have many InnoDB tables but there is no problem accessing them. Only a few particular tables are giving this issue. Also, I found that its a common error, but there is no direct solution.https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=error%20code%201146