# MySQL using all RAM

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ubuntu

I am trying to restore SQL dump file of around 750 MB on Ubuntu 16.04 VM with 1GB RAM and MySQL 5.7.21.

I have configured `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768MB`, `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 128M` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1`.

To stop killing from OOM-killer `OOMScoreAdjust=-1000` is added to `mysql.sqevice` file.

When restoring is started mysqld utilized all memory.

```
root@IA6-OA-DB-01:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            987         925          11           0          50          19
Swap:           632         621          11
```

It starts to kill all processes.

```
root@IA6-OA-DB-01:~# mysql -uroot -proot -D OA2017 < OA2017.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Killed
```

Syslog

```
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.058935] Out of memory: Kill process 24895 (mysql) score 17 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.477043] Out of memory: Kill process 2226 (sssd_be) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:35 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.747574] Out of memory: Kill process 2283 (sssd_be) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.903214] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84990.971431] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84991.208088] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:36 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84991.329594] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:38 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84993.369239] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:39 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84994.124215] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:41 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84995.928253] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:44 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [84999.295787] Out of memory: Kill process 1587 (smbd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:48 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85003.091554] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:49 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85003.498436] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:50 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85005.624213] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:13:55 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85007.717901] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85014.623037] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85016.130481] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:02 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85017.218094] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:09 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85024.577427] Out of memory: Kill process 858 (sssd) score 3 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:09 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85024.857977] Out of memory: Kill process 321 (systemd-journal) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:11 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85025.128881] Out of memory: Kill process 14831 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:11 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85025.173233] Out of memory: Kill process 14831 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85048.414654] Out of memory: Kill process 15546 (bash) score 2 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85048.545329] Out of memory: Kill process 1057 (nginx) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:34 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85049.430812] Out of memory: Kill process 15513 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85060.595291] Out of memory: Kill process 1629 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85060.884189] Out of memory: Kill process 1629 (sshd) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85061.268085] Out of memory: Kill process 1061 (nginx) score 1 or sacrifice child
Apr 14 13:14:46 IA6-OA-DB-01 kernel: [85061.470392] Out of memory: Kill process 1280 ((sd-pam)) score 1 or sacrifice child
```

After this VM gets rebooted.
What could be the problem? and What variables do i need to change to make it run?

Comment: +1 for a very good first question - if only they were all as polished as this! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL using all RAM

As per MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) Buffer pool size must always be equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances). If you configure [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) to a value that is not equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances), buffer pool size is automatically adjusted to a value that is equal to or a multiple of [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size) * [innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances).

**innodb_buffer_pool_size**

InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this parameter up to **`80%`** of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on `32bit` systems you might be limited to `2-3.5G` of user level memory per process, so do not set it too high.

**innodb_buffer_pool_instances**

The number of regions that the InnoDB buffer pool is divided into. For systems with buffer pools in the multi-gigabyte range, dividing the buffer pool into separate instances can improve concurrency, by reducing contention as different threads read and write to cached pages.

For example, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is set to `8G`, and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is set to `16`. `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` is `128M`, which is the default value.

**`8G`** is a valid `innodb_buffer_pool_size` value because `8G` is a multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`=**16** * `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size`=**128M**, which is **2G**.

```
shell> mysqld --innodb-buffer-pool-size=8G --innodb-buffer-pool-instances=16

mysql> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
+------------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024 |
+------------------------------------------+
|                           8.000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

**innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size**

`innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` defines the chunk size for InnoDB buffer pool resizing operations. The [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) parameter is dynamic, which allows you to resize the buffer pool without restarting the server.

To avoid copying all buffer pool pages during resizing operations, the operation is performed in **`chunks`**. By default, innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size is **`128MB`** (134217728 bytes). The number of pages contained in a chunk depends on the value of [innodb_page_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_page_size). innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size can be increased or decreased in units of 1MB (1048576 bytes).

> **Important:** Care should be taken when changing [innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size),
>   as changing this value can automatically increase the size of the
>   buffer pool. Before changing innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size,
>   calculate the effect it will have on [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)
>   to ensure that the resulting buffer pool size is acceptable.

For further your ref [here](https://scalegrid.io/blog/calculating-innodb-buffer-pool-size-for-your-mysql-server/)

Comment: I have configured `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768M` which is multiple of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 128M` and  `innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1`. The problem is mysql using all RAM which is 1GB and swap also.

Comment: @Shivaditya, As per your RAM size, It is better to go with the MySQL default configuration value of 128MB for InnoDB buffer pool size.

Comment: Tried with default configuration, still all RAM is fully utilized.

Comment: @Shivaditya, How many there is **MAX Connection**?

Comment: Max connections are 1000.

Comment: @Shivaditya, The default value is 151.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92452/discussion-between-shivaditya-and-md-haidar-ali-khan).

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan - 80% of only 1G is _much too big_!

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan - `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` is only used when dynamically changing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  That is not really worth discussing for the OP's problem.  Any resizing should be done in my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

One big problem:  On a 1GB machine, `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 768MB` is *much too big*.  It is leading to swapping (terrible for performance) or OOM (even worse).  200M might be OK.

Some amount of space is used for each connection; I would not set `max_connections` higher than 20.

What other settings have you raised?  If anything, you should lower settings -- MySQL, out of the box, is not designed for a tiny 1GB machine (or VM).

And no more than 1 for `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`.

Make the changes in the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf and restart (if it has not crashed again).

Answer (score 0):

This problem could have been solved without reconfiguring: Recreate the mysqldump using `--skip-extended-insert`. This will cause each row in the dump to the to be inserted one-by-one.

This will control the amount of memory dedicated to doing inserts without expanding MySQL Packets.

I once did this at my old job with a bare-metal PC (really old job) that had 1 GB RAM. I had to load a MySQL database on a Windows Machine. It would crash repeatedly because of doing bulk inserts as mysqldumps usually do. I had to recreate the dump with `--skip-extended-insert`. Then, I was able to load the database without crashing.

There were two downsides to this:

1. The dump was 10 times bigger (This of INSERT INTO for every row written as text)
2. It longer 4 times longer to load

Other than a bigger VM, redoing the mysqldump is the best option.

I have suggested this before

- `Jul 10, 2015` : [Windows crashes on doing sql dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/windows-crashes-on-doing-sql-dump/106605#106605)
- `Apr 15, 2015` : [mysqldump Error 2013](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97846/mysqldump-error-2013/97866#97866)
- `Feb 13, 2015` : [When does creating a .sql backup with mysqldump become too large?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91903/when-does-creating-a-sql-backup-with-mysqldump-become-too-large/91911#91911)