# MySQL 5.7 Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have a PC running windows 7 and MySQL 5.6. Data is uploaded to the server via java. They work nicely without any error.  I just migrate to windows 10 and MySQL 5.7. The same program is used to upload data without any error in the java side. I also check that the data are written into the database. However, i got lots of [note] in the error log

```
Aborted connection 48 to db: 'XXX' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I have try following ([MySQL Error Reading Communication Packets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/mysql-error-reading-communication-packets?newreg=c5f2655b24fc4a6f84c728f890e64b36)) and same result occurred.  Whats wrong ?

```
    [client]
no-beep
port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8


port=3306

datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7\Data

character-set-server=utf8

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="YANJAR2.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="YANJAR2-slow.log"
long_query_time=10

log-error="YANJAR2.err"

server-id=1

secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"

max_connections=1024

query_cache_size=20M

table_open_cache=2000

tmp_table_size=136M

thread_cache_size=9

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=262M

key_buffer_size=8M

read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=8M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M

innodb_log_file_size=512M

innodb_thread_concurrency=9

innodb_autoextend_increment=64M

innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

innodb_open_files=300

innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

back_log=80

flush_time=0

join_buffer_size=256K

max_allowed_packet=256M

max_connect_errors=200

open_files_limit=4161

query_cache_type=1

sort_buffer_size=256K

table_definition_cache=1400

binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

sync_master_info=10000

sync_relay_log=10000

sync_relay_log_info=10000

bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```